# Word for: to exacerbate but not cause

Tags: single-word-requests

Intended Meaning: Suppose I am feeling upset. There is a clear cause for this feeling, but I also know that if I wasn't also in a particular circumstance, I would be better equipped to temper my unhappiness. Therefore, the circumstance only changes the magnitude of how upset I feel, but it does not explain the cause of the feeling.

Connotation: Positive. I'm trying to suggest that the circumstance made visible the cause, which might have been suppressed otherwise. The function of making the cause visible is useful.

Context: In a discussion, someone tried to discount how I felt because of this circumstance: "You only feel upset because X was happening at the same time." I'm trying to say that X only helped me realize some underlying discontent.

Non-example: A word like exacerbate does not include the "making visible" aspect that I'm looking for.

What is a good word to describe the circumstance? I will accept an answer which can describe the role of amplifying in order to make perceptible.

Comment: +1 for promoting and reinvigorating the word 'exacerbate.'

Comment: What specifically do you mean by ‘word’? Are you looking for a noun for the circumstance (“the circumstance is a ___”), an adjective (“it is a ___ circumstance”), a verb (“the circumstance ___ my situation”), or something else entirely? And what’s wrong with _exacerbate_? Seems to me that means exactly what you’re looking for.

Comment: An adjective. I thought of exacerbate as I was writing the question. I think it works as a verb, but I wanted to collect other people's opinions to see if there are other adjectives (besides exacerbating).

Comment: As it stands now, your question will probably be closed; to avoid that, have a look at the [check-list on this page](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) to see what information should be included in a single-word-request question, and then edit your question to make sure you’ve covered all those points.

Comment: I believe the question should now be permissible according to guidelines. Thank you for the link - I'll keep it in mind for future questions.

Comment: You still fail to reveal the research you've done.

Comment: And why is "expose" not the obvious choice?

Comment: *magnify* has both these connotations, but not necessarily at the same time :-(. Perhaps it's not quite emphatic enough for you.

Comment: Exacerbation doesn't imply causation; I vote for just "exacerbate"

Comment: Agonist and Antagonist get used in the sense you want in Biochemistry and Physiology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agonist

Answer (score 1):

If you want to describe an event Z which made evident the causal relation from X to Y, without being in any way the cause of Y, you might use the verb "to highlight" which in this case would mean:
to bring to light, to make prominent, obvious the cause X.

> Draw special attention to: '*the issues highlighted by the report*'

(Oxford English Dictionary)

Of course the *issues* weren't caused by the report.

Answer (score 0):

To *bring out* can mean to "develop and display" (talent), and could be transferable to a feeling or state, as in

Seeing the corpse brought out my grief. Seeing her lying there brought out my underlying feelings.

The *seeing* intensified the feeling so that it was exposed.

> To bring into clearness, distinctness, or prominence; to develop and display (talent)

(*Oxford English Dictionary*)

Answer (score 0):

A word somewhat similar to *expose*, *highlight*, and *magnify*
is ***illuminate:***

> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/illuminate):
>
> - to make lucid or clear; throw light on (a subject).
> - to enlighten, as with knowledge.
>
> [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illuminate):
>
> - to make clear : elucidate
> - to bring to the fore : highlight
>     <a crisis can *illuminate* how interdependent we all are>

Other options (which are particularly related to *expose*) include ***unmask:***

> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unmask):
>
>   to reveal the true character of; disclose; expose.
>
> [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unmask):
>
>   to reveal the true identity or nature of (someone or something)

and ***unveil:***

> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unveil):
>
>   to reveal or disclose by or as if by removing a veil or covering: 
>     to unveil a monument; to unveil a secret; to unveil a truth.

> [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unveil):
>
> - to remove a veil or covering from
> - to make public : divulge, reveal <a good time to *unveil* their plans>